# Automatically update second worksheet when rows are deleted on the first worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one worksheet with information and a second worksheet that uses formulas to determine values based on what is in the first spreadsheet. Is there any way that when I delete or add a row in the first worksheet and have the second worksheet automatically updated. i.e. not show #REF! ??

Answer (score 0):

[Excel help to lock formulas from adjust on cell insert](https://superuser.com/questions/787549/excel-help-to-lock-formulas-from-adjust-on-cell-insert/787596#787596)

This question was asked just a few weeks ago. I linked to the answer I gave there.